# How to stay anonymous on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to give someone a share link for a Google Sheet, but when they join the sheet, my name, and profile picture is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is "No". In fact, its not just your name and profile picture, your email address is also accessible.